# Why it is showing referenced before assignment in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anybody tell me where I am doing wrong in this following Python program?

I am trying to create a Paint like application but it is showing errors.

File "E:\project\New folder\paint_new.py", line 33, in use_eraser

```
activate_button(eraser_button, eraser_mode=True)
```

File "E:\project\New folder\paint_new.py", line 36, in activate_button

```
active_button.config(relief=RAISED)
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'active_button' referenced before assignment

> name 'eraser_on' is not defined

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
import tkinter as tk



DEFAULT_PEN_SIZE = 5.0
DEFAULT_COLOR = 'black'



def setup():
    old_x = None
    old_y = None
    line_width = choose_size_button.get()
    color = DEFAULT_COLOR
    eraser_on = False
    active_button = pen_button
    c.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
    c.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', reset)

def use_pen():
    activate_button(pen_button)

def use_brush():
    activate_button(brush_button)

def choose_color():
    eraser_on = False
    color = askcolor(color=color)[1]

def use_eraser():
    activate_button(eraser_button, eraser_mode=True)

def activate_button(some_button, eraser_mode=False):
    active_button.config(relief=RAISED)
    some_button.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    active_button = some_button
    eraser_on = eraser_mode

def paint(event):
    line_width = choose_size_button.get()
    paint_color = 'white' if eraser_on else color
    if old_x and old_y:
        c.create_line(old_x, old_y, event.x, event.y,
                           width=line_width, fill=paint_color,
                           capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
    old_x = event.x
    old_y = event.y

def reset(event):
    old_x, old_y = None, None

root = tk.Tk()

pen_button = Button(root, text='pen', command=use_pen)
pen_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

brush_button = Button(root, text='brush', command=use_brush)
brush_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

color_button = Button(root, text='color', command=choose_color)
color_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

eraser_button = Button(root, text='eraser', command=use_eraser)
eraser_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

choose_size_button = Scale(root, from_=1, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
choose_size_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

c = Canvas(root, bg='white', width=600, height=600)
c.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

setup()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you learned what a local variable is? You seem to be expecting all variables to be accessible from every function.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'active_button' referenced before assignment` seems to imply that your trying to use a local variable out of its enviroment, try using `global active_button` before defining `active_button`? woah another read through that piece of code literally takes variables from every function even though they are local? Try parameter passing or global-izing the variables. (BTW if you global every variable it's not the most happy piece of code so you should watch out if variables are local or global) yeahhh you might wanna redesign your code a bit.

Comment: Try using "global" keyword, even though then your code will be a nightmare. Add `globat old_x, old_y, line_width...` with the list of ALL variables at the beginning of each function.

Comment: @Богдан Опир seems a bit overkill?

Comment: @jadu uh y'know if you wanna do canvas stuff i would just suggest javascript and HTML for canvas related, just an opinion, python is good too. (but its just much easier on JS and HTML because of canvas tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smart solution would be to use sth. like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
import tkinter as tk



DEFAULT_PEN_SIZE = 5.0
DEFAULT_COLOR = 'black'


class ABC:
    def setup(self):
        self.old_x = None
        self.old_y = None
        self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
        self.color = DEFAULT_COLOR
        self.eraser_on = False
        self.active_button = self.pen_button
        self.c.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.paint)
        self.c.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.reset)

    def use_pen(self):
        self.activate_button(self.pen_button)

    def use_brush(self):
        self.activate_button(self.brush_button)

    def choose_color(self):
        self.eraser_on = False
        self.color = askcolor(color=self.color)[1]

    def use_eraser(self):
        self.activate_button(self.eraser_button, eraser_mode=True)

    def activate_button(self, some_button, eraser_mode=False):
        self.active_button.config(relief=RAISED)
        some_button.config(relief=SUNKEN)
        self.active_button = some_button
        self.eraser_on = eraser_mode

    def paint(self, event):
        self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
        self.paint_color = 'white' if self.eraser_on else self.color
        if self.old_x and self.old_y:
            self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                               width=self.line_width, fill=self.paint_color,
                               capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
        self.old_x = event.x
        self.old_y = event.y

    def reset(self, event):
        self.old_x, self.old_y = None, None
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.pen_button = Button(self.root, text='pen', command=self.use_pen)
        self.pen_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.brush_button = Button(self.root, text='brush', command=self.use_brush)
        self.brush_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.color_button = Button(self.root, text='color', command=self.choose_color)
        self.color_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.eraser_button = Button(self.root, text='eraser', command=self.use_eraser)
        self.eraser_button.grid(row=0, column=3)

        self.choose_size_button = Scale(self.root, from_=1, to=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.choose_size_button.grid(row=0, column=4)

        self.c = Canvas(self.root, bg='white', width=600, height=600)
        self.c.grid(row=1, columnspan=5)

        self.setup()
        self.root.mainloop()
ABC()
```

Learn simple OOP principles! Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Also, add the default value argument when you create the scale

Comment: @БогданОпир can you show me how can i make the canvas transparent and fullscreen.

Comment: @beepbeep-boop as far as I understand, not entirely. `self` is the same for each method of an object, in js it's `this`. ABC is a class, by using `ABC()` I create an object, class instance, each method can access an object through `self`.

Comment: @jadu I don't know any way to make it transparent, but to make it fullscreen add `self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` and `self.root.resizable(False, False)` at the and of `__init__` function

Comment: @БогданОпир can i use `self.root.attributes("-alpha", 0.1)` to make the canvas,window transparent and by using `self.root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` only the window is becoming fullscreen but the canvas is same

Comment: The canvas background is a different value. I couldn't even get `self.root.attributes("-alpha", 0.1)` to work.

Comment: @БогданОпир its working for me but how can i get canvas in fullscreen

Comment: Try setting up autoexpand for canvas

Comment: I've failed, hope you'll succeed.